# Upgrading from Node v5.1.0 to v12.16.1 running into error

Tags: python, node.js, npm, node-gyp

I am reviving an old Node project, the .nvmrc was `v5.1.0`. I used `nvm` to start using v12.16.1, and now when I run `npx i` or `npm i` I get the following output:

https://gist.github.com/ruevaughn/1d465d509aa04800954d43da4ef581c7

The main message as I can derive from that gist is here:

```
18 warnings and 18 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/cjensen/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/cjensen/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node" "/Users/cjensen/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/cjensen/projects/inusa/inusa-api/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@12.0.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-import@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@8.0.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-import@^1.16.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package loopback-testing-helpers is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/cjensen/.npm/_logs/2020-02-25T20_43_56_990Z-debug.log
```

Here is [2020-02-25T20_43_56_990Z-debug.log](https://gist.github.com/ruevaughn/486fc0556e50e7fbf3cd7c944f2c7830)

---

I tried to run `node-gyp` manually and got the following error:

```
    ~/p/inu/inusa-api    update-node +1 !1 ?1 ▓▒░ node-gyp rebuild                                ░▒▓ ✔  30m 58s   12.16.1   14:41:49  
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@6.1.0
gyp info using node@12.16.1 | darwin | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.5 found at "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7"
gyp info spawn /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/cjensen/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/cjensen/projects/inusa/inusa-api/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/cjensen/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/cjensen/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.16.1/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/cjensen/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.16.1',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/cjensen/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/cjensen/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.16.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/cjensen/projects/inusa/inusa-api',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /Users/cjensen/projects/inusa/inusa-api) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/cjensen/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/cjensen/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/node" "/Users/cjensen/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/cjensen/projects/inusa/inusa-api
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Apparently it's not ok. So, it looking to me like node-gyp was compiled with node v6.10 (I did initially upgrade from 5 to 6 before I decided to 'go for it').

When I do a

```
which -a node-gyp                                      
/Users/cjensen/.nvm/versions/node/v5.1.0/bin/node-gyp
```

I see node V5.1.0 is the path it's currently set to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: node-gyp comes in as a dependency of npm itself, which comes in as bundled dependency for node. Tell `nvm` to install the latest Node 12, and make doubly sure it's set to use that, first? (And probably uninstall Node 5, because you're going to have to clean that up anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using an old version of bcrypt (0.8.7).  You need to use at least version 3.0.6 to work with Node 12.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#version-compatibility

Comment: Interesting I didn't pick up on that. So I deleted my package-lock.json file, I assumed that would resolve dependencies such as that?

Comment: The package-lock.json file will always lock dependencies within the versions allowed by the package.json.  You might have a caret range that restricts you to major version 0 (see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004).  Try running `npm i bcrypt@latest --save` to update to the latest version of bcrypt.